# How to wait for Requests to finish using Selenium CDP

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, fluentwait

I want to use CDP (or any other way) in java to dynamically wait in Selenium until specific requests are fully served. Normally I am waiting using FluentWait for specific elements to be seen on page but these requests have no immidiate effect on the UI itself. Instead of that, they are being used when clicking in the UI. Problem is that often in automation selenium proceeds with clicking once it finds element (e.g. logo) and since these requests are not fully loaded then no data are being shown in it as a consequence of not finished request.

I wanted to use CDP and its addListener but dont know how to filter properly there on which requests to wait and to give it conditional wait for status e.g. 200. Any help on that? Thank you :)

Comment: Looks like a design flaw to me, if Selenium can do it, you user too, what happens when your user clicks on the UI and the request is not finished yet? You should probably implement either a loader, or that the button is disabled until the request finishes. Then you will have a critera for Selenuim to know when to click too

Comment: Totally agree. Unfortunately I am left without a loader :(. However IF in this case does not solve the issue. Problem is how to solve it without loader.

Comment: I never used Selenium with Java, but you can add a hidden criteria, for example in HTML I would probably add a class to the body, something like `content_loaded`

Comment: @Kaddath you mean within the tests? Within product i can see many ways how to fix it. Problem is that this is third party for me and hence cannot much manipulate with it. So even If i would put this element I would need to know when to put it and we are back to the original question :)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question, I thought you had control over the code you are testing. I'm not an expert on this, so apart from a timeout if performance is not a concern, I don't know

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid trying to use Selenium 4 methods to access the CDP as I have seen performance issues.

Instead I would suggesting using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.kklisura.cdt/cdt-java-client.

You will initially need to get the CDP port by using `getCapabilities` of the instantiated WebDriver. There is a capability called `"goog:chromeOptions"` and within this there is a property called `"debuggerAddress"`.

https://github.com/kklisura/chrome-devtools-java-client will explain how to now use this address to connect to the CDP.

With this, you should be able to use the `Network` domain (https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/) to listen to 3 events:

- onRequestWillBeSent
- onResponseReceived
- onResponseFailed

Each of the events will provide a unique `requestId` and you can use that to create some kind of mechanism to track requests when they are made and when they are completed.

Such a mechanism could be a `Set<String>` that you could consider as "all requests finished" when that `Set` is empty.

All these events are "fire and forget"  from the Chrome side, so shouldn't impact the perceived performance of your application under test.

How this is implemented would be dependent on your current framework and your AUT.

For example, `onRequestWillBeSent` provides access to the URL, so you could filter based on that and ignore requests you don't care about.

Also, dependent on your AUT, you may experience "hanging" requests if navigation occurs while requests are still in progress. To combat this, you can also subscribe to `onFrameNavigated` from the `Page` domain, and use this event to clear the `Set`

Comment: Yep I tried something similar using Selenium and its CDP - however it came to me pretty unpractical to use. As basically I would have to create on every navigation Listeners on specific requests and keep looping for their arrival - then closing them. I thought Selenium could already solve this kind of things by functionality that would allow you to look into requests-responses in network tab directly.

Comment: I was able to define the listeners once when the browser opened, then had a generic regex  that caught all traffic as it started and then completed.

What problems do you have?

Comment: The problem I see is that when you refresh the page then you have same url requests called - you need to handle duplicities - with each refresh. This will get also even more problematic when one test will fail. And even more when you have SSEs on the application which are basically not closable. Thatswhy i wonder if there is something what you can ask for this type of things rather then creating whole logic layer. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: @Karcel each request has a unique id and you would use that to decide when a request has finished rather than the URL.

Infact, the `onResponseReceived` & `onResponseFailed` messages only contain the request id